# Create Skype like click to call IE pluggin

Tags: click, call

The pluggin must search the phone number present in the webpage and highlight it . On Click the highlighted phone number , voip call must be triggered() .
VOIP client i have . How to uncomplish this in IE ,Firefox , Outlook Mail .
Any updates , or any sample code i can get . I am new to Java technologies ,like java script.
I am confused with extensions,pluggins or addons ...